# Changing column names in a data frame in R with the specific name

Tags: r

my output required in the column name is
    now i am getting as

```
Column A    Column B
x = 128
Y = 145
in the code as we need to write is "Column A (N=x)" "Column B (N=Y)"
How we will call the value in X in quotation mark.

but i need the column name as below

Column A    Column B
(N=128)      (N=145)
```

how we need to create this
  Could someone help me to figure this out?

Comment: May be using `sprintf` i.e. `sprintf('%s (N=%d)', 'Column A', 128)`.  You could create a function with `sprintf` i.e. `f1 <- function(stri, num) {sprintf('%s \n(N=%d)', stri, num)}; cat(f1('Column A', 128), '\n')`

Comment: Were you given that data frame like that or did you do a calculation first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `paste` or `sprintf`

```
 names(df1) <- paste0(names(df1), ' (N=', c(x,Y), ')')
 names(df1)
 #[1] "Column A (N=128)" "Column B (N=145)"
```

It may be better to keep it in a single line instead of multi-line column names.  For printing, we can use `cat`

```
  cat(paste0(names(df1), '\n (N=', c(x,Y), ')\n'))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame("Column A" =1:5, "Column B"= 6:10, check.names=FALSE)
x <- 128
Y <- 145
```